# Sample space for 4 yes or no's stringed together

Tags: abstract-algebra

I've recently found interest in pure mathematics, but I came up with something I haven't seen regarding set notation and couldn't find anything in regards to the approach I took.

Anyways, I was given a problem in my introductory statistics course after our first day, which basically asks the simple question for us to define a sample space of 4 objects that have either a y or n event. I could do the following:
$$
S=\{nnnn, nnny, nnyn, nnyy, ..., yyyy\}
$$

However, I came up with the following, which may or may not be simpler (or even correct).
I begin by defining a set$\ \textbf{X} =\{y,n\}. $

I then define a binary operation * on the set given by the following truth table:

$$
\begin{array} {|r|r|}\hline * & y & n \\ \hline y & yy & yn \\ \hline n & ny & nn \\ \hline  \end{array}
$$
And I note that $\ (S, *) $ is a semigroupoid and $\ X\subset S $.

Finally, the sample space would be defined as:
$$
S=\cup\{x*x*x*x|x\in\textbf{X}\}
$$

Would this be correct notation? If no, what could I do to approach the problem in a similar way?

Comment: You've defined the "Cartesian product."

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Ah yes, that is right.

Comment: Some things went wrong here. Your operation $\star$ is not a binary operation on the set $X$. For example, $y\star y=yy$, which is not in $X$. Nor is it a binary operation on $S$, as $y$ and $n$ are not in $S$.

Comment: @Andijvie Ah yes, because a binary operation is defined as $\ S \times S \to S $ and I fail closure. If I omit the operation being a binary one, would this then be correct or is there still other flaws?

Comment: I'm afraid more things went awry. We don't have $X\subseteq S$. $S$ is not a semigroupoid. You probably want $x\star x\star x\star x$ to equal $xxxx$, but then $\left\{x\star x\star x\star x\mid x\in X\right\}$ only contains $yyyy$ and $nnnn$. The intersection sign in the last equality therefore doesn't do anything and the set you obtain isn't equal to $S$ at all, as it will only contain two elements.

Comment: @Andijvie That was meant to be a union sign, but I see what you mean by it only contains yyyy or nnnn since I maintain the same four elements.  With a fresh mind, I also see that I would have to define a new operation for each subsequent operation since the * operator only works with y/n. Yikes. I was undoubtedly overthinking this and it would be much easier to just use a 4-tuple$\ S = \{(a,b,c,d) | a,b,c,d \in X\} $.